# GStreamer: Introduce delay/gap/shift to audio

Tags: python, audio, synchronization, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I have the following pipeline setup in gstreamer:

two pulse audio sources (pulsesrc) from two seperate usb audio interfaces and one pulse audio sink (pulsesink). I'm combining the two incoming audio streams using the adder component. Unfortunately there is a slight delay between the two audio channels.

```
pulsesrc1 --- queue --- audioconvert --- audioresample --- |
                                                           | adder --- queue --- | pulsesink
pulsesrc2 --- queue --- audioconvert --- audioresample --- |
```

I'm using the system time/clock for syncing. Both Audio-Interfaces are connected to the same usb-hub. I'm guessing that the audio has already a slight delay before it even gets picked up by the sources (due to different clocks).

This is why I'd like to introduce a delay/gap/shift to the first audio channel (the 2nd lags slightly behind) to compensate for that.

So far I tried setting the property "min-threshold-time" of the first queue. Unfortunately the pipeline compensates for this delay and both audio streams get equally delayed. I've also checked out the element "audioecho". Unfortunately it is missing a "dry/wet" property. This means the original signal gets always played at its original time and then after that the delay tail kicks in (which does not help me at all).

Any further ideas how to solve this problem? Maybe adding a gap of silence? Or other parameters I might have been missing.

I've implemented this pipeline using Python. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the min threshold time / bytes in queue to delay sending the data over the rest of the pipeline? I think it should work. Only if that does not go for this:

http://gentrans.sourceforge.net/docs/head/gst-entrans-plugins/html/gst-entrans-plugins-shift.html

or modify frie0r delay plugin for audio.

Comment: Thanks av501! I've tried setting the min threshold time before. Unfortunately this does not work because GStreamer's automatic delay compensation evens out the delay in the other audio path. I'll have a look at the shift plugin. I'll let you know how it worked.

Comment: Have you ever worked with the shift-element? This simple test pipeline does not work - no shift takes place: gst-launch-0.10 pulsesrc device=alsa_input.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_Sound_Blaster_X-Fi_Go__Pro_00201613-00-Pro.analog-stereo ! shift delay=2000 ! queue ! pulsesink device=alsa_output.usb-Creative_Technology_Ltd_Sound_Blaster_X-Fi_Go__Pro_00201613-00-Pro.analog-stereo

Comment: No havent used it myself. Perhaps some debug prints might tell you what is going on? GST_DEBUG=3 or 4. Btw, in the simple pipeline how do you know shift has taken place? I don't think that will happen. From what I read it shifts the timestamps. So if you mux it into a container you should see shifted timestamp. However otherwise the pipeline won't start unless there is one output till the sink (unless your pipeline is in live mode. If your sink has a live mode, enable it).

Comment: Looked into the debug-log (level 3-5). Nothing suspicious there. So does this mean, that I'm not actually delaying the audio coming from the input to the output so that it is being played back a specific time (eg 2 seconds) later? It just shifts the timestemp and players like VLC take the timestamp and delay the audio accordingly? I tried muxing the data, too - but the shift element with a delay of 2000000 microseconds has no effect at all on the muxed file (in terms of an actual delay). Gonna have a look at the actual timestamps now (have to find a tool for that first).

Comment: Ok, I got in touch with the developer of the Shift-element. It was really just changing the timestamps and did not delay the signal at the output of a source. He was kind enough to add that feature (already commited to GitHub). Now it's possible to set the property "running-time=TRUE" which delays the signal. This works with simple pipelines such as "inputsrc ! shift ! outputsrc" but fails when trying to direct the shifted audio stream into a muxer. Guess I'll have to come back to your initial advice and write my own gstreamer plugin. Anyway, thanks again for your help!